# Do we still need to use &pound; or &#163; instead of the British Pound £ sign in html?

Tags: html, character-encoding, html-entities

There's nothing on http://caniuse.com about this that I can see, but in limited testing on very up-to-date browsers it seems the British pound symbol `(HTML5 + UTF-8 page)` no longer needs the `html` entities used.

I wonder if anyone knows if its safe to just use the `£` sign in modern browsers now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not depending on the browsers or the operating system. It depends on the charset that you store and display the data.

If you have the `<meta>` tag with UTF-8 and your database with a compatible charset, and you use a server-side script that's writting in UTF-8, you can use the symbols instead the HTML entities.

HTML entities (`&euro;` or `&pound;` are safely between charsets, so doesn't matter what charset is defined. But the good practices said that you need to develop in the same charset all your code.